# Import dump file containing a database dump to dbeaver

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

I have a database  dump in this`db_2022.dump` binary file that I'm trying to import to dbeaver, but I haven't found a way to import the database so I can see it.

I found the below in the dbeaver forum but when I try to follow the instructions and create a new connection I don't see any option I can select that will open this document.

https://dbeaver.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=895

> Edit: The database and version is PostgreSQL 12
> . I'm not trying to
> dump it to an existing db rather I want to create a new one with this
> dump.
> the dump command looks like this: pg_dump -h blah.amazonaws.com -Fc -v --dbname="blah2" -f "/tmp/dump/20220203.dump".
> And it will be the same version PostgreSQL 12

Comment: Not near enough information. Need: 1) What database did you dump from, Postgres, MySQL and it's version? 2) What was the dump command? 3) What database are you trying to import into, Postgres/MySQL and version?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I've updated my answer with some edits, thank you for responding!

Comment: Except you have not specified the `dump` command or indicated whether you are dumping restoring form/to the same version of Postgres.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver sorry! updated pls let me know if more info is needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to not use DBeaver at all.

Do:

**UPDATED** with correct command.

```
--In psql
CREATE DATABASE new_db;
--Exit psql
--At command line
pg_restore -d new_db -h <the_host> -p <the_port> -U postgres /tmp/dump/20220203.dump
```

To work in Dbeaver directly see [Backup/Restore](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Backup-Restore).

Comment: I've selected this as the best answer, but if there a way to do this directly in dbeaver as well?

Comment: See my update to the answer.

Comment: In my case, "CREATE new_db;" didn't work for me, I did need to run "CREATE DATABASE new_db;"

Comment: Well that was a stupid on my part, corrected the command. Thanks.